# Obj-c - Convert String to NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to convert text that appears in my cell's `UILabel` to an `NSDate` format. For some reason, my below code doesn't work, even though my string (timeEnd) contains a value? The output of timeEnd is: 19-08-2018 17:38 , and yet for some reason my conversion result is (`NULL`)?

**ViewController.m**

```
NSString *timeEnd = filteredSwap[indexPath.row][@"endswaptime"];
cell.endTime.text = timeEnd;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM y hh:mm a zzz"];
NSLog(@"Date is: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeEnd]);
```

Comment: Take a look at your format, `EEE, dd MMM y hh:mm a zzz` - how does this match your input `19-08-2018 17:38 `?  I suspect that a format similar to `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm` will give you a better result

Comment: @MadProgrammer Omg, duh... Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to get your date:

```
     NSString *timeEnd = filteredSwap[indexPath.row][@"endswaptime"];        
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSLog(@"Date is: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeEnd]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The output of timeEnd is: 19-08-2018 17:38 , and yet for some reason my conversion result is (NULL)?

The format of your string doesn't match the format you use for the date formatter. `NSDateFormatter` therefore can't create a valid date using the format you gave it, and it returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSString *timeString = @"01/03/2018";

        NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

        result = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];
```